# When I try to sync my iPad, I get an "Unknown Error (-39)"

Tags: ipad, itunes, data-synchronization

[image]

It still seems to sync most things - the error occurs late in the sync toward the end of the last step, which seems to be photo-related, and my apps are up to date, etc.

The main thing I've noticed that's off is my pictures - when I open the pictures app, I get a message saying:

> iTunes Sync Needed - High Resolution
>   images synced via itunes are missing. 
>   Connect your device to the computer
>   you sync photos from and launch iTunes
>   to sync them.

Since the issue seems like it might be photo-related, I tried repairing my Aperture library's permissions and database - no help.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Kyle, that worked- thanks!  (Although it makes me feel a little like the guy who calls support without restarting.)  Care to make it an answer, so I can accept it, and the next person who runs into it will find the right solution?

Comment: ok, done, glad it worked for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try turning off photo sync completely, syncing, and then turning it back on.